# Trouble with jquery's append and prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append, prepend

I use the following code to check whether or not a certain div exists. And if it doesn't it adds it to the dom in the proper place.

```
if (!($("#col"+lastSlide).length))
{
    $('#schDisplay').prepend('<div id="col' + (lastSlide) + '"></div>');
}
```

My problem is that when this if statement checks again for a div that had already once been appended/prepended, it doesn't see the div that I added. So it will continue to add the div that was already prepended/appended.

Is there any way this issue can be fixed?

more code:

```
//fillin added column
function fillElement(colnum)
{
    var URL = 'schedule.php';
    $("#col"+colnum).text("Loading...").show();
    $.post(URL,{fecolnum: colnum}, 
    function (data)
    {
        $("#col"+colnum).html(data).show();
    });
}
//...irrelevant code...

    // Create event listeners for .arrows clicks
      $('.arrows')
        .bind('click', function(){
            numberOfSlides++;
            // Determine new position
            if ($(this).attr('id')=='arrow_right')
            {
                lastSlide++;
                currentPosition++;
                if (!($("#col"+lastSlide).length))
                {
                    $('#schDisplay').append('<div id="col' + lastSlide + '" class="schColumn" style="float: left; width: ' +slideWidth+ 'px"></div>');
                    fillElement(lastSlide);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lastSlide--;
                currentPosition--;
                if (!($("#col"+lastSlide-2).length))
                {
                    $('#schDisplay').prepend('<div id="col' + (lastSlide-2) + '" class="schColumn" style="float: left; width: ' +slideWidth+ 'px"></div>');
                    fillElement(lastSlide-2);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You need to show more context. I cannot tell from your question how '#col'+lastSlide and '#schDisplay' are related. From what you've shown me, it's entirely possible that '#col'+lastSlide doesn't change when you prepend to #schDisplay.

Comment: Not enough information. Please post the relevant code.

Comment: I updated the question and added more code. I have the feeling that I may need to use .live() somewhere, but i'm not sure where or what the proper syntax would be.

Comment: You say that it keeps adding the divs, but you never check for the same div id twice. You increment `lastSlide` every time you click the `.arrows` links, so it adds a new div with a new id every time.

Comment: it increments lastSlide when the first button is pressed and decrements lastSlide when the second is pressed. The problem occurs when I increment and then decrement or vice versa. Divs with exact same ID are added when this occurs. (I see it through firebug)

Comment: upon further debugging i figured it out. It wasn't an issue with prepend/append like some suggested. It was a pair of parentheses missing xD. ty for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much context to go off of, but checkout this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JEgEv/) I made from what you gave me.

Notice the line where I've made a comment that you can comment **out** the increment statement. Basically, this is how you can test what happens when "lastSlide" is the same value.  (versus if "lastSlide" is indeed a different value).

You might just try debugging your actual code and make sure that lastSlide has the value you actually expect.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're saying that it keeps adding the `div` if you do the same thing again. However, I can't reproduce this. The following code shows one div. According to you, it would show two divs.

```
lastSlide = 1;
if (!($("#col"+lastSlide).length))
{
    $('#schDisplay').prepend('<div id="col' + (lastSlide) + '"></div>');
}
if (!($("#col"+lastSlide).length))
{
    $('#schDisplay').prepend('<div id="col' + (lastSlide) + '"></div>');
}
```

If I didn't miss something, your problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
if (!($("#col"+lastSlide).length)) {
  var newdiv = $('<div id="col'+lastSlide+'"/>');
  $('#schDisplay').prepend(newdiv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It keeps adding because your if condition is always true.

I haven't tested this though...

Can you try something like this to see if it helps?

```
var len = 0;
len = $("#col"+lastSlide).length;
if (len < 1)
{
    $('#schDisplay').prepend('<div id="col' + (lastSlide) + '"></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery filters to remove the selected div if it has already been prepended to. This should work for your particular scenario:

```
$('#schDisplay').filter(':not(:has(div[id^=col]))')
```

This says "select the div with id 'schDisplay' and then remove it from the selection if it has any descendent divs with ids start with 'col'".

In your example, you would chain on your prepend statement to this code like so (no need for an if statement):

```
$('#schDisplay').filter(':not(:has(div[id^=col]))').prepend('<div id="col' + (lastSlide) + '"></div>');
```

A special note: I believe that the :has selector is a jQuery content filter selector, meaning that it will not work without jQuery. You are clearly using jQuery, but readers with different implementations should keep this in mind.